# How to assign an ID integer value to each row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: SQL Table]

I have created a table in SQL as shown, and I have realised that I forgot to add a Primary Key.
I figured the best way to add a primary key is to add a new column called ID, and then assign a corresponding value to each row, i.e. ID = 1, ID = 2, ID = 3 and so on; and then convert it to a Primary Key column.

I cannot assign the ID column as a Primary Key because it contains NULL values currently.

Is there a way that I can iterate through each row and add +1 to the ID column, within SQL?
Or, alternatively, is there an easier way to assign a Primary Key in this scenario?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Doesn't making it an identity column automatically populate it?

Comment: Are you doing a SQL course? This sort of data looks fairly typical for educational examples, and this example looks like part of a module on normalization, since the table does not seem to be in third normal form (unless a person's favourite meal depends upon their team, or vice versa!). What is the natural key for the table? It must have one. If you are having trouble identifying one, it is probably because the schema is not normalized.

Comment: drop your id add then readd it as identity: ALTER TABLE Football DROP COLUMN ID; ALTER TABLE FootBall ADD ID INT IDENTITY

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE x
SET
    ID = rn
from (
SELECT
    ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_column) AS rn
FROM
    table_name

) x;
```

Something like this should work.